# Find duplicate words in notepad++

Tags: regex, duplicates, notepad++

I have a file with the file hierarchy and its corresponding CRC32 code:

```
Folder A\Folder C\File three.txt         56efd95f
Folder A\File one.txt                    b8e1b873
Folder A\Folder B\Folder D\File four.txt 56efd95f
Folder A\Folder B\File two.txt           21e8e9c9
```

I am using notepad++ and I need to know a regular expression capable of finding rows with the same CRC32.
In this example I expect to find line 1 and line 3.

I know with `\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,8}$` I can Match the CRC32 but how can I check if these matches are repeated?

Moreover if I wanted remove everything but the CRC32, why is not working the expression `.*(?!\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,8}$)` to replace the matches with an empty string and get a clean list of CRC32?

Comment: Alternatively you could import the file into Excel/LibreOffice Calc and sort by the CRC column. Then scroll through the file and identity duplicates.

Comment: @Robert Regex is funner

Comment: See my answer below for finding duplicated CRC codes. If you're still interested in removing everything except the CRC codes then try `.*\s(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,8}$)` and disable the `. matches newline` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
/([\da-f]{8}$)(?=.*\1)/gms
```

- `([\da-f]{8}$)` - find a CRC code
- `(?=.*\1)` - make sure the CRC code appears again

https://regex101.com/r/fpIOCN/1

In Notepad++ just make sure to enable ". matches newline"

[image]

Comment: @Thefourthbird Notepad++ is not the same thing as using regex101. If I click "Find Next" then it highlights the next one. Fwiw, Notepad++ is a really great tool for anyone starting to program!

Comment: @Thefourthbird I'm not sure what's going on with your Notepad++ but mine cycles through each match one at a time and highlights it. My Notepad++ is also configure to subhighlight whatever I have highlighted. Notice in my screenshot that the first `56efd95f` is a darker green than the second one. The first one is what is cursor-highlighted, the second one is Notepad++ being a bro and showing me additional matches.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Settings -> Preferences -> Highlighting -> "Smart Highlighting" Enable

Comment: @Thefourthbird If you're confused by the lookahead assertion then try `([\da-f]{8}$).*\1`

Comment: Ok, I had smart highlighting already on :-) So just for the test, if you use your pattern `([\da-f]{8}$)(?=.*\1)` and replace it with `XXXXX` you get 2 replacements?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Correct!

Comment: O dear, then my Notepad is really off. Well, I learned a new thing then. I will remove the comments and +1. Thanks!

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't mind the comments. If OP is similarly confused then hopefully they read the comments :)

Comment: For what it's worth, in my NP++ V7.9 I get a single match only for line 1 using the same example data from the question https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN3QU.png

Comment: Thank you very much! Really grateful

Answer (score 1):

To find the duped repetitions:

```js
(?s)\h([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$(?=.*\h\1$)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XDXXB5/3).

To remove all but the CRC32 codes:

```js
.*\h([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$
```

Replace with `$1`. See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/XDXXB5/2). Then, *Edit* -> *Line Operations* -> *Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending* and after that *Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines*.

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \h                       horizontal whitespace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]{8}           any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9' (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        end of a line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \h                       horizontal whitespace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        end of a line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solution working and very clear explanation, what a pity that there can only be one accepted answer

Comment: @Carlos You are welcome. You can upvote, click the UP arrow, to notify everyone the answer is helpful.

Comment: I up voted your answer the first time I read it, but a message was shown saying that due to my low reputation the system wouldn't display it but take it into account. Now, people have voted my question, I've got some points and the system displays my vote ;)